# decision diagram and decision tree difference

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computability

What are the difference between decision diagram and decision tree? Is BDD a type of DD? what are the other type of DD? what are the algorithms used for it

Answer (score 1):

Decision tree is a tree.

Discision diagram is not necessarily a tree.

A binary decision diagram is a directed acyclic graph.

See the diagram at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram